# Clover Boot EFI file on non-UEFI computer

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, gpt

So I have heard about booting into Clover from a BIOS boot and booting back to the first bootloader but in UEFI mode. Is there any detailed way of how to make such a configuration? I can't seem to find any online and the ways I have heard of involve MBR; however, I need to have a GPT configuration so I can be able to make more than three or four primary partitions. Is there a way to do this? I don't want to use UEFI DUET; I followed [Rod Smith's tutorial](https://www.rodsbooks.com/bios2uefi/) on a USB flash drive and there were complications with IDE and AHCI mode and other things like that, so I want to avoid anything like DUET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question touches two interlocked issues:

- BIOS vs. UEFI boot
- GPT vs. MBR boot

The problem you run into is, that Clover needs a BIOS boot, but BIOS boot implies MBR boot. So obviously there needs to be some magic involved - turns out, this is quite straight forward: A disk can carry both, an MBR and a GPT partition table, and they don't need to carry the same information - this is called a hybrid partition table.

- So what you need to do is create a GPT partition table to your needs (including one partition for Clover - best put this first to make the next step easier)
- Then create a "protective" MBR-style partition table, that contains the Clover partition as bootable, and everything else in a single primary partition of type "EF".

After you have installed Clover, when the BIOS-style boot runs via the MBR (installed by Clover), it will start Clover, which will in turn read the GPT partition table to boot the rest.
This implies, that while BIOS sees only one bootable partition, Clover can see many.

I have successfully used this method to triple-boot between Ubuntu, Windows and MacOS.